# Will the mkfs reformat my USB/external HDD?

Tags: filesystem

I am having trouble with my external HDD because it appears to not have any filesystem type. Will running the mkfs command completely reformat my HDD resulting in losing my data?

Comment: This is the kind of question that needs very specific answers and therefore also detailed information. mkfs formats a partition, usually not a harddisk. If you want to create a new partition table, then you'll want to use a different tool. If you're using Ubuntu Desktop, I'd recommend using Disks for these things.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any bugs on the linux kernal,it shows `wrong filesystem type` error when you connect `USB or External HDD` to the pc.Run the below command on the terminal to update your `linux-kernal`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Once the kernal was successfully installed,reboot your pc.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to explain that claim?

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount your hdd manually with `sudo mount /path/to/hdd /mnt` and look what the error is. If it throws an exfat error, you have to install exfat-fuse and exfat-utils with `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`.

This is a problem that I experience every time I reinstall linux, maybe you have the same problem.

/path/to/hdd is, for example, /dev/sdb1